# What clipboard format does InDesign use?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to create data to paste into InDesign and I'm using the following code to copy my data to the clipboard:

```
Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData("dms", xml.toXMLString());
```

But when I paste it into InDesign, it shows the code rather than the formatted content. I don't know if the ClipboardFormat is correct and I don't know if my data is correct (it is the whole IDMS XML document). Does anyone have a working example or tell me what's wrong?

Here is what I get when I check the formats property of the Clipboard.generalClipboard.formats array. It also contains the format value:

```
air:file list:null
air:url:null
```

Comment: For Windows there are utilities that can show the contents of the clipboard. (My guess is InDesign uses an internal format to represent its own data, but maybe you can mimick it.)

Comment: I'm on a Mac but I can look for something like this. Thanks

Comment: It looks like it's creating a file reference. I'll update with an answer when I get more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is copying a file or file reference to the clipboard.